# Add "My questions" and "My answers" menus to the Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

If the Android app had something like "My questions" or "My answers" menus, it would be easier to revise my questions/answers.

Comment: I have bad news for you. Android app development is frozen.

Comment: @alexolut ... Thanks... then how can I contribute to the development of it?

Comment: @KYHSGeekCode you can't. My best advice is don't use the app, get used to the responsive design of the full site in a browser which is going to be improved and has the team's focus these days. (You can use Chrome or Firefox on mobile devices as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By now I am using **my recent activity** menu of `my profile` menu. This half satisfies the purpise of me.